# Design time error

Tags: winforms

I am facing design time error in WINForm. 
I am not able to view my controls in design time.
My code is executing perfectly fine, but I am not able to view the controls.
I am getting following error:

To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved:

**"The designer loader did not provide a root component but has not indicated why. "**

Looking forward your co=operative response.

Regards,
Shweta

Answer (score 1):

These are fun to troubleshoot.

If you go to the solution explorer, there will be an option to display all files.

From there, when you hit the plus out on your form, not only will there be a .cs file but also a .designer.cs file.

Open the designer file and see if you get an error or warning from the compiler.

If you have source control, have a look at the revision history on this file, if it's not too far back that you had the error appear then you may be able to isolate the change that caused it.  If you don't have source control, then this would be a good time to start using it.